# WebView in Flutter with html from a string

Tags: html, flutter, plugins, webview

I am trying to make an application with flutter and I need to pass html with a string to webviewer but I always get an error, I have tried this code but it tells me that the controller is not initialized, is there an easier way? The plugin's github doesn't make it clear to me. Thank you so much

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class MyWebViewWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final String html;

  MyWebViewWidget({required this.html});

  @override
  _MyWebViewWidgetState createState() => _MyWebViewWidgetState();
}

class _MyWebViewWidgetState extends State<MyWebViewWidget> {
  late WebViewController _controller;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // #docregion platform_features
    late final PlatformWebViewControllerCreationParams params;

      params = const PlatformWebViewControllerCreationParams();


    final WebViewController controller =
    WebViewController.fromPlatformCreationParams(params);
    // #enddocregion platform_features

    controller
      ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
      ..setBackgroundColor(const Color(0x00000000))
      ..setNavigationDelegate(
        NavigationDelegate(
          onProgress: (int progress) {
            debugPrint('WebView is loading (progress : $progress%)');
          },
          onPageStarted: (String url) {
            debugPrint('Page started loading: $url');
          },
          onPageFinished: (String url) {
            debugPrint('Page finished loading: $url');
          },
          onWebResourceError: (WebResourceError error) {
            debugPrint('''
Page resource error:
  code: ${error.errorCode}
  description: ${error.description}
  errorType: ${error.errorType}
  isForMainFrame: ${error.isForMainFrame}
          ''');
          },
          onNavigationRequest: (NavigationRequest request) {
            if (request.url.startsWith('https://www.youtube.com/')) {
              debugPrint('blocking navigation to ${request.url}');
              return NavigationDecision.prevent;
            }
            debugPrint('allowing navigation to ${request.url}');
            return NavigationDecision.navigate;
          },
        ),
      )
      ..addJavaScriptChannel(
        'Toaster',
        onMessageReceived: (JavaScriptMessage message) {
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            SnackBar(content: Text(message.message)),
          );
        },
      )
      ..loadRequest(Uri.parse('https://flutter.dev'));

    // #docregion platform_features

    // #enddocregion platform_features

    _controller = controller;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WebViewWidget(
      html: widget.html,
      controller: _controller,
    );
  }
}

class WebViewWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String html;
  WebViewController controller;

  WebViewWidget({required this.html, required this.controller});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WebViewWidget(
      html: '''
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
          <head>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
          </head>
          <body>
            $html
          </body>
        </html>
      ''',
      controller: controller,
    );
  }
}
```

He probado con diferentes plugins como flutter_webviewplus, flutter_webview_plugin: ^0.4.0 y nada, además webview tal cual no me deja usarlo.

Comment: Please edit your question because you should use all the words in English.

Answer (score 2):

I'm also showing a static html string in a webview in my application. But I'm instantiating the webview controller in a different way, and loading the html with the `loadHtmlString` function from controller.

**Controller**

```
WebViewController wbController = WebViewController()
    ..enableZoom(true)
    ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
    ..setBackgroundColor(const Color(0x00000000))
    ..setNavigationDelegate(
      NavigationDelegate(
        onNavigationRequest: (NavigationRequest request) {
          if (request.url.startsWith("https://")) {
            launchUrl(Uri.parse(request.url));
            return NavigationDecision.navigate;
          } else {
            return NavigationDecision.prevent;
          }
        },
      ),
    )
    ..loadHtmlString("""
      <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
          <head><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.7"></head>
          <body style='"margin: 0; padding: 0;'>
            ${html.content}
          </body>
        </html>
      """);
```

**Webview**

```
WebViewWidget(
    controller: wbController,
)
```